# How can I use VS Code to update extensions via commandline?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I can't [find a command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions) to update my install extensions from the terminal.

Of course I use `code --install-extension` to install extensions. But how should I update them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--help` docstring for `--install-extension` says:

> `--install-extension <ext-id | path>` Installs **or updates** an extension. The argument is either an extension id or a path to a VSIX. The identifier of an extension is '${publisher}.${name}'. **Use `--force` argument to update to latest version**. To install a specific version provide `@${version}`. For example: `vscode.csharp@1.2.3`.

VS Code 1.86 and up also support updating all extensions via commandline, with `code --update-extensions` (see issue ticket [#56578](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56578)). If you don't pass a `--profile` argument, only extensions for the default profile are updated. If you pass a `--profile` argument, only extensions for that profile will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

As of vscode v1.86 you can update **ALL** your extensions from a command line:

```
code-insiders --update-extensions  // this works now, in the Insiders edition

code --update-extensions          // should work as of v1.86 Stable
```

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56578

Some extensions still require a reload though.